# How to properly use K-Nearest-Neighbour?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, classification, nearest-neighbor

I've generated some data in R and applied the Bayes Classifier to the points. They are all classified as either "orange" or "blue". I'm having trouble getting accurate results from the `knn` function because I think the classes ("blue", "orange") are not properly being linked to `knn`.

My training data is in a data frame `(x, y)`. My classes are in a separate array. I did it like this for the Bayes Classifier - it was much easier to plot. Now, however, I don't know how to "plug in" my classes into `knn`. Using the following code is very inaccurate. I have changed `k` to be many different values for testing, all are inaccurate.

```
library(class)

x <- round(runif(100, 1, 100))
y <- round(runif(100, 1, 100))
train.df <- data.frame(x, y)

x.test <- round(runif(100, 1, 100))
y.test <- round(runif(100, 1, 100))
test.df <- data.frame(x.test, y.test)

cl <- factor(c(rep("blue", 50), rep("orange", 50)))

k <- knn(train.df, test.df, cl, k=100)
```

Again, my sorted classes are in an array `classes` further up in the code.
Here is my full document. The above code is at the very bottom.

```
library(class)

n <- 100
x <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
y <- round(runif(n, 1, n))

# ============================================================
# Bayes Classifier + Decision Boundary Code
# ============================================================

classes <- "null"
colours <- "null"

for (i in 1:n)
{

    # P(C = j | X = x, Y = y) = prob
    # "The probability that the class (C) is orange (j) when X is some x, and Y is some y"
    # Two predictors that influence classification: x, y
    # If x and y are both under 50, there is a 90% chance of being orange (grouping)
    # If x and y and both over 50, or if one of them is over 50, grouping is blue
    # Algorithm favours whichever grouping has a higher chance of success, then plots using that colour
    # When prob (from above) is 50%, the boundary is drawn

    percentChance <- 0
    if (x[i] < 50 && y[i] < 50)
    {
        # 95% chance of orange and 5% chance of blue
        # Bayes Decision Boundary therefore assigns to orange when x < 50 and y < 50
        # "colours" is the Decision Boundary grouping, not the plotted grouping
        percentChance <- 95
        colours[i] <- "orange"
    }
    else
    {
        percentChance <- 10
        colours[i] <- "blue"
    }

    if (round(runif(1, 1, 100)) > percentChance)
    {
        classes[i] <- "blue"
    }
    else
    {
        classes[i] <- "orange"
    }
}

boundary.x <- seq(0, 100, by=1)
boundary.y <- 0
for (i in 1:101)
{
    if (i > 49)
    {
        boundary.y[i] <- -10 # just for the sake of visual consistency, real value is 0
    }
    else
    {
        boundary.y[i] <- 50
    }
}
df <- data.frame(boundary.x, boundary.y)

plot(x, y, col=classes)
lines(df, type="l", lty=2, lwd=2, col="red")

# ============================================================
# K-Nearest neighbour code
# ============================================================

#library(class)

#x <- round(runif(100, 1, 100))
#y <- round(runif(100, 1, 100))
train.df <- data.frame(x, y)

x.test <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
y.test <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
test.df <- data.frame(x.test, y.test)

cl <- factor(c(rep("blue", 50), rep("orange", 50)))

k <- knn(train.df, test.df, cl, k=(round(sqrt(n))))
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for reproducibility, you should set a seed before generating a set of random numbers as done by `runif`or running any simulations/ML algorithms that are stochastic. Note that in the code below, we set the same seed for all instances generating `x`, and a different seed for all instances generating `y`. That way, the pseudo-randomly generated `x` is always the same (but different from `y`), and likewise for `y`.

```
library(class)

n <- 100
set.seed(1)
x <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
set.seed(2)
y <- round(runif(n, 1, n))

# ============================================================
# Bayes Classifier + Decision Boundary Code
# ============================================================

classes <- "null"
colours <- "null"

for (i in 1:n)
{

    # P(C = j | X = x, Y = y) = prob
    # "The probability that the class (C) is orange (j) when X is some x, and Y is some y"
    # Two predictors that influence classification: x, y
    # If x and y are both under 50, there is a 90% chance of being orange (grouping)
    # If x and y and both over 50, or if one of them is over 50, grouping is blue
    # Algorithm favours whichever grouping has a higher chance of success, then plots using that colour
    # When prob (from above) is 50%, the boundary is drawn

    percentChance <- 0
    if (x[i] < 50 && y[i] < 50)
    {
        # 95% chance of orange and 5% chance of blue
        # Bayes Decision Boundary therefore assigns to orange when x < 50 and y < 50
        # "colours" is the Decision Boundary grouping, not the plotted grouping
        percentChance <- 95
        colours[i] <- "orange"
    }
    else
    {
        percentChance <- 10
        colours[i] <- "blue"
    }

    if (round(runif(1, 1, 100)) > percentChance)
    {
        classes[i] <- "blue"
    }
    else
    {
        classes[i] <- "orange"
    }
}

boundary.x <- seq(0, 100, by=1)
boundary.y <- 0
for (i in 1:101)
{
    if (i > 49)
    {
        boundary.y[i] <- -10 # just for the sake of visual consistency, real value is 0
    }
    else
    {
        boundary.y[i] <- 50
    }
}
df <- data.frame(boundary.x, boundary.y)

plot(x, y, col=classes)
lines(df, type="l", lty=2, lwd=2, col="red")

# ============================================================
# K-Nearest neighbour code
# ============================================================

#library(class)
set.seed(1)
x <- round(runif(n, 1, n))

set.seed(2)
y <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
train.df <- data.frame(x, y)

set.seed(1)
x.test <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
set.seed(2)
y.test <- round(runif(n, 1, n))
test.df <- data.frame(x.test, y.test)
```

I think the main problem lies here. I think you want to pass to `knn` the class labels obtained from the Bayes classifier i.e., the vector `classes`. Instead, you are passing `cl` which are just sequential labels of cases in `test.df` i.e., are not meaningful.

```
#cl <- factor(c(rep("blue", 50), rep("orange", 50)))

k <- knn(train.df, test.df, classes, k=25)
plot(test.df$x.test, test.df$y.test, col=k)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks! You're an all-star. So, if I wanted to draw a knn boundary line, I'd just have to iterate through my test points and `classes`, find the outermost points belonging to "orange", then trace a line around them?

Comment: @KingDan, not sure but you could try that. In the meantime, if the answer nailed the original question, you could accept it ;-), cheers